# jQuery onclick show/hide

Tags: jquery

I need to hide a container when I click outside of it. I managed to get it working, sort of, but now the container wont close on second click on the toggle button.

- `.first` is the search button which toggles the `.search`
- `.search` is the search container
- `.second` is the category button which toggles the `.category-dropdown-1`
- `.category-dropdown-1` is the second container - category container

`.searchfade` and `.category-container-1-fade` are the hide-show classes with animations

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").click(function() {
    $(".search").toggleClass('searchfade');
  });
  $(".second").click(function() {
    $(".category-dropdown-1").toggleClass('category-dropdown-1-fade');
  });
  $("*").mouseup(function(e) {
    var subject = $("#search");
    if (e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length) {
      document.getElementById("search").className = "search";
    }
    var subject2 = $("#category-dropdown-1");
    if (e.target.id != subject2.attr('id') && !subject2.has(e.target).length) {
      document.getElementById("category-dropdown-1").className =
        "category-dropdown-1";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.search {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3a54d6;
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 11;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;  
}

.searchfade {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3a54d6;
  height:100px;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.category-dropdown-1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #3a54d6;
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.category-dropdown-1-fade {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3a54d6;
  height:auto;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="under-navigation">
  <div id="search" class="search">
    DIV 1
  </div>
  <div id="category-dropdown-1" class="category-dropdown-1">
    <div class="category-menu">
      DIV 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it will be better to see full example (with html)

Comment: i edited it and pasted the HTML also

Comment: You need to also include your CSS

Comment: I don't see a toggle button in your HTML

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/52cq7o5p/3/ here it is

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue and here is the solution for that, As per the [documentation on jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#example-1).

You have to add the one global variable:

```
var count = 0;
```

And then you need to use this in your toggleClass function.

```
$( ".second" ).click(function() {

        $(".category-dropdown-1").toggleClass('category-dropdown-1-fade', count%2 == 0);
      count++;
    });
```

Here is the complete code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
var firstcount = 0;
var secondcount = 0;
 $( ".first" ).click(function() {
   $(".search").toggleClass('searchfade',firstcount%2==0);
   firstcount++;
 });

 $( ".second" ).click(function() {
      
    $(".category-dropdown-1").toggleClass('category-dropdown-1-fade', secondcount%2 == 0);
      secondcount++;
 });

    $("*").mouseup(function(e)
    {
        var subject = $("#search"); 
        if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length)
        {
            document.getElementById("search").className = "search";
        }

        var subject2 = $("#category-dropdown-1");
        if(e.target.id != subject2.attr('id') && !subject2.has(e.target).length)
        {
            document.getElementById("category-dropdown-1").className = "category-dropdown-1";
        }
    });

});
```

```css
body
{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navigation
{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #3a54d6;
 height: 75px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation a 
{
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 75px;
}
.first , .third , .fourth , .fifth
{
 width:75px;
}
.first
{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.second
{
 width:170px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.first , .second
{
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.third , .fourth , .fifth
{
 float: right;
 border-left:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.logos
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top:21px;
}
.category-text
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 7px;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-right: 23px;
 float: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.under-navigation
{
 width:100%;
 background-color: #3a54d6;
 height: 250px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.search
{
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity:0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin:0;
 width: 100%;
 height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3a54d6;
    border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 11;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
    
}

.searchfade
{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity:1;
 transition: 0.3s;
 margin:0;
 width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3a54d6;
    height:100px;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ffffff;
}


@keyframes fade {
    0%   {margin-top:15px;}
    100% {margin-top:-1px;}
}

.search-form
{
 width: 70%;
 height:40px;
 margin:28px auto;
}
.search-bar
{
 background: url(search.png) no-repeat scroll 4px 5px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 height:40px;
 width: calc(50% - 170px);
 border:none;
 float: left;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 margin-left: 5px;
}
.location-bar
{
 background: url(placeholder.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 5px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 height:40px;
 width: calc(50% - 175px);
 border:none;
 float: left;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.main-logo-container
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0;
 height:75px;
 margin:auto;
 width:200px;
}
.main-logo
{
 font-size: 35px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0;
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ffffff;
 margin-top: 17px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
.category-button
{
 margin:0;
 border:none;
 height: 44px;
 float: left;
 border:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 width:10%;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    height: 44px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    width: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


.search-btn
{
 margin:0;
 border:none;
 height: 44px;
 float: right;
 border:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}


.category-dropdown-1
{
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity:0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin:0;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
    background-color: #3a54d6;
    border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.category-dropdown-1-fade
{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity:1;
 transition: 0.3s;
 margin:0;
 width: 100%;
    background-color: #3a54d6;
    height:auto;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    border-top:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 60px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 6;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.category-menu
{
 display: block;
 height:auto;
 width:80%;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.category-menu a 
{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 50px;
 width: 230px;
 margin:5px;
}
.icon-back , .icon-back2 , .icon-back3 , .icon-back4 , .icon-back5 , .icon-back6 , .icon-back7 , .icon-back8 , .icon-back9 , .icon-back10 , .icon-back11 , .icon-back12
{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 25px;
 float: left;
}
.icon-back
{
 background: url(car.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back2
{
 background: url(home.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back3
{
 background: url(pc.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back4
{
 background: url(ball.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back5
{
 background: url(pet.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back6
{
 background: url(chair.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back7
{
 background: url(tshirt.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back8
{
 background: url(baby.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back9
{
 background: url(umbrella.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back10
{
 background: url(wrench.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back11
{
 background: url(truck.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-back12
{
 background: url(briefcase.png) no-repeat scroll  9px 8px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.category-description
{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 5px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="navigation">
  <a id="first" class="first"><img id="image1" class="logos" src="search.png" alt="Search"></a>
  <a id="second" class="second"><img id="image2" class="logos" src="menu.png" alt="Menu"><p id="text1" class="category-text">Категория</p></a>
  
  <div class="main-logo-container">
   <p class="main-logo">Битака</p>
  </div>
  <a class="third" href="#"><img class="logos" src="log-in.png" alt="Log-in"></a>
  <a class="fourth"><img class="logos" src="users.png" alt="Users"></a>
  <a class="fifth"><img class="logos" src="add.png" alt="Add"></a>
 </header>

<div class="under-navigation">

<div id="search" class="search">
 <form class="search-form">
  <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
     <button type="button" class="dropbtn">Категория</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  <input class="location-bar" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Location">
   <button class="search-btn" type="submit">Търси</button>
 </form>
</div>
  <div id="category-dropdown-1" class="category-dropdown-1">
   <div class="category-menu">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Автомобили</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back2">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Дом и градина</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back3">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Електроника</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back4">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Спорт и хоби</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back5">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Животни</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back6">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Обзавеждане</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back7">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Мода и облекло</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back8">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">За бебето</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back9">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Екскурзии и почивки</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back10">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Услуги</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back11">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Машини и оборудване</p>
     </a>
     <a href="#">
      <div class="icon-back12">
      </div>
       <p class="category-description">Работа</p>
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```